# Creating A Simple ATM program

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a simple ATM program with 5 buttons ($20, $60, $100, Other Amount, and Withdrawal).  I need to create a confirm box when the money buttons are pressed and have the amount deducted from a text box when the withdraw button is pressed.  Here is my code:

```
<form action="" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="$20" onclick='accept())'/>
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Withdrawal" onclick=''/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="$60" onclick='accept()'/>
        </td>
        <td>Current Balance

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Current Balance" value="5000.00" onchange=''/>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="$100" onclick='accept()'/>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Other Amount" onclick=''/>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </form> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var balance=50000;  

function withdraw(amount)       
{

var sure = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Withdraw This Amount?");
if(true)
{
balance = balance - amount;
}else
{
alert("No Withdrawal Made");
}
alert("Your Balance Is "+balance);

function 


</script>
```

Please help!  This is driving me crazy.  Thanks!

Comment: replace `if(true)` by `if(sure)`

Comment: The fix for this is likely to be a nice walk outside and maybe a drink/food :). Then come back and see what you see.

Comment: Your JS code is really messy and your HTML contains self-closing tags, I would recommend doing some more research on HTML5 standards and general JS.

Comment: this is a mess `"Current Balance"` is not a valid type, there is no `accept` function, and the js looks like its been through a blender

Comment: It worked with the if(true) when I placed it where I have accept() (which I forgot to change back).  Only thing is I don't want it to withdraw the money when I click the money buttons.  I want that to happen when I click the withdraw button.

Comment: Obviously if I knew Javascript I wouldn't be coming to this website.  I am aware it is messy, I am trying to figure things out as I go along.  Hence why I am asking the experts.  Yeesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Lets have a look at some of the issues;

Indent your code properly, it will help you spot errors more easily.

Use an editor like notepad++ or better still an IDE that will show your syntactical errors

Don't use tables in your markup for layout purposes, learn css

```
<form action="" >
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="button" value="$20" onclick='accept())'/> // you have an extra closing brace here
</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Withdrawal" onclick=''/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="$60" onclick='accept()'/>
    </td>
    <td>Current Balance

    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="Current Balance" value="5000.00" onchange=''/> //Current balance is not a valid type
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="$100" onclick='accept()'/>
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Other Amount" onclick=''/>
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var balance=50000;  

function withdraw(amount)   //this function should be called accept not withdraw 
 { //you didn't close this brace

  var sure = confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Withdraw This Amount?");
  if(true)  //should be if (sure)
      {
        balance = balance - amount;
      }else{
        alert("No Withdrawal Made");
      }
       alert("Your Balance Is "+balance);

     function  //this shouldn't be here


</script>
```

Comment: Andrew this is just an assignment for a computer class.  We can only use what we've learned and that table is what we taught for now.  I'm sure there are more complex ways to do this but I need it to be simple.  Also I am using Notepad++.  Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question clearly, but I think you need to confirm an amount for your "Other Amount" button, of your ATM application. You are suppose to use "prompt", usage of it is just like an alert box.

```
<input type="button" value="Get" onclick="prompt('How Much Amount, you want to withdraw?')">
```

your code can be something, like shown above.

Comment: Thank you hiren.  However, when the Other Amount button is pressed, I need it to say:  "Sorry.  This Function is not available."

Comment: then, instead of prompt, the way I've used in the above code. you can use alert instead of it.

onclick="alert('How Much Amount, you want to withdraw?')"

Comment: I ended up doing that and putting "Sorry.  This function is not available."  Thanks, hiren!

Comment: My issue is taking that withdraw function and placing it with the withdrawal button.  When I click $20, $60, or $100 i need to be able to click the withdraw button and have the text box updated with the new amount. Does that make sense?